# Making legend for subplot with scatter points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a legend for my subplot using Python. Here's part of my code:

```
L1, =axs[1].scatter(x = phi, y = Evala, color = 'teal',s=60)
```

This method works when I was not using subplot, but now it returns me the following error message:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable PathCollection object
```

I'm not pretty sure how I can fix this issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has an object which should not be present there as you are assigning values to the variable `L1`

```
L1, =axs[1].scatter(x = phi, y = Evala, color = 'teal',s=60)
```

Try this,

```
L1 =axs[1].scatter(x = phi, y = Evala, color = 'teal',s=60)
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma after `L1` that shouldn't be there, resulting in the error.